# How could I get this Vim binding to work?

Tags: vim

[qnamebuf](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3217) plugin description says:

> `<S-F4>` opens an explorer from the current working directory showing all files which are not in a hidden directory (one that starts with '.')

I'm not very good with Vim, but I imagine `S-F4` is a capital `S` followed by `F4`. However, when I press `S`, I find myself in insert mode, and pressing `F4` after this, just adds an `F4` in the window. What should I do to make the command work? I am running gVim under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `S` stands for <kbd>Shift</kbd>. So try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I see the force is strong in you :)